# python pexpect using spawn to run a bash file in sonic unit

Tags: python, linux, bash, automation, pexpect

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash", ['/home/admin/eeprom_test_01.sh'])
child.expect("Type 'Continue' to proceed, else abort:")
child.sendline("Continue")
child.expect("Select Capitaine revision\\(EVT or DVT\\):")
child.sendline("DVT")
child.expect("EEPROM Device: COMe")
return child
```

This is the error received,

### EOF: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x7fa381be9978>
command: /bin/bash
args: ['/bin/bash', '/home/admin/eeprom_test_01.sh']
buffer (last 100 chars): b''
before (last 100 chars): b'/bin/bash: /home/admin/eeprom_test_01.sh: No such file or directory\r\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: 127
flag_eof: True
pid: 16303
child_fd: 7
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
0: re.compile(b"Type 'Continue' to proceed, else abort:")

Comment: for now got the solution with  "echo -e  "Continue\nDVT\n" | ./eeprom_test_01.sh"  instead of just ./eeprom.sh and giving inputs of Continue and DVT, that can be ran in default common lib cmds

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.